# We want to display values in an ascending order using while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, count, numbers, descendant

I have the following code and when I enter a number, the terminal should display the values from 1 to the entered number, meaning in an ascending order.
As the code is, it displays values in descending order.
How can I change my code to make it to an ascending order?

```
// Example5.java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        count = in.nextInt();
        while (count > 0) {
            System.out.println(count);
            --count;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of starting at `count` and count down, start at `1` and count up.

Comment: You'll need another variable.

Comment: @Turing85 how Is that done?

Comment: @Karl create a new variable, let it start by `0`, rewrite the `while`-condition, print the new variable instead of `count` and increment the new variable instead of decrementing `count`. A more detailed answer would give a full working solution, which I will not provide since this is an exercise, and there is no point in me solving the exercise for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a better way to do it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example5 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

         int count=0;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
           int number = in.nextInt();
            while (count <= number) {
                System.out.println(count);
                count++;
            }
    }

}
```

Having a variable for the number and a variable for the counter is easier to understand
**if you want it in ascending order, you should start from the smaller number (0) and then increase the counter to get to the greater number (input)**